# How to extract parameter definitions using regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract parameter definitions from a Jenkins script and can't work out an appropriate regex (I' working in [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com) which supports PCRE8).

Here's how the subject looks like:

```
pipeline {                                 
  agent none                                  
  parameters {                                
     string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: 'bar')
     string(name: 'goo', defaultValue: 'hoo')
  }                                           
  stages {                                    
    stage('action') {                       
      steps {                             
        echo "foo = ${params.foo}"      
      }                                   
    }                                       
  }                                           
}
```

I would like to get the individual param definitions captured in group 1 (in other words: I'm looking for a results that reports two matches: `string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: 'bar')` and `string(name: 'goo', defaultValue: 'hoo')` ), but the matches are either too long or too short (depending on greediness).

My regex:
`parameters\s*{(\s*\D*\(.*\)\s*)*}`  (dot matches nl)

Parameter types may vary, so my best idea was to use `\D*` for those (any # of non-digits). I am suspicious that this captures more than I expected - but replacing that with  `\w` did not help.

An alternative idea was
`parameters\s*{(\s*(\w*)\(([^\)]*)\))*\s*}`

which seemed more precise wrt matching parameter types and also the content of the parens - but surprisingly that returned `goo` only and skipped `foo`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your regex platform/flavor?

Comment: Duh - thanks for asking! It's PCRE8, I have updated the question.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Dyalog APL - also updated q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PCRE` you can use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode:

```bash
(?m)(?:^\h*parameters\h*{|(?!^)\G).*\R\h*\w+\(\w+:\h*'\K[^']+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoTMpD/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable MULTILINE mode
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^\h*parameters\h*{`: Match a line that starts with `parameters {`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`:
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `.*`: Match anything
- `\R`: Match a line break
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word chars
- `\(`: Match `(`
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word chars
- `:`: Match a `:`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `'`: Match a `'`
- `\K`: Reset all the matched info
- `[^']+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `'` (this is our parameter name)

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't exactly give what I was looking for - and I'm even unable to fix the statement :(( Could you have another look at it, pls?  (I updated the q to be more precise about what I'm looking for...)

Comment: Did you check attached demo that shows matches as `foo` and `goo` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. And now I did again - and guess what: finally I managed to tweak it as needed. Thanks a lot!